# Check whether object became invisible from top or bottom of scroll list

Tags: listview, unity-game-engine

I'm having a Unity vertical scroll list with a lot of data. 
The problem here is that I need to know whether a `List Item` in the scroll list `OnBecameVisible` from top or bottom of screen. The default function is called when it became visible from any edge while I need to use different code when it became visible from different edge.

How to handle it?

Comment: Doesn't the method callback provide the information on which side of the screen it activated from? In any case, this is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start.

Comment: Sorry. I'm a newbie with Unity and have to finish a project in short time. As far as I know, OnBecameVisible/Invisible is trigger whenever object appears on screen. How can I make it tell me which side it comes from ?